# Instagram Authentication no longer shows sign in inputs just serves instagram.com

Tags: authentication, callback, instagram

So I know that instagram just did some API updates which I am trying to implement. But the very first step no longer seem to work:

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code

This very first step used to send you to a sign in page where you input your username and password, if you were already signed in then it would send you to a page confirming that you want the app to tap into your profile.

Today this no longer does so, despite already having tried to clear local cache etc...

So here is a curl response on the matter. Any lights on this would be amazing and please note that the client ID and secret are correct:

```
curl -IL https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/\?client_id\=3bfds87f9asd6f8sd76f44a6390b\&redirect_uri\=http://localhost:3000/auth/instagram\&response_type\=code
HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Content-Language: en
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Vary: Cookie, Accept-Language
Location: https://api.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login=&next=/publicapi/oauth/authorize/%3Fclient_id%3D3b44dsf798asdf68d7s6f8d7a6390b%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%3A//localhost%3A3000/auth/instagram%26response_type%3Dcode
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Date: Fri, 12 Jun 2015 18:45:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=164f0e68ds9f6ds8f76s7df6382e07ee3; expires=Fri, 10-Jun-2016 18:45:33 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0

HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
Content-Language: en
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Vary: Accept-Language
Location: https://instagram.com/
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Date: Fri, 12 Jun 2015 18:45:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 10411
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 12 Jun 2015 18:45:34 GMT
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=e6c925f87d6f87ds6f877a36c70ad9; expires=Fri, 10-Jun-2016 18:45:34 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Set-Cookie: mid=VXsozafsdjhjkadf7TPuiiFJi; expires=Thu, 07-Jun-2035 18:45:34 GMT; Max-Age=630720000; Path=/
Vary: Cookie, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Same here. I hope it is a bug.

Comment: I tried again, it seems to be working. Can you check it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad it was a bug. Everything is normal now.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram API bug. It's back up and running.